# What's the SIMPLEST way to make a DJANGO Registration page?

Tags: python, django, registration, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I'm relatively new to Django but have spent countless hours this past week learning how to make webapps. I've bounced around from numerous tutorials promising to make a user registration, but they have all led my pages to crash and turn completely blank and white.

I'm now starting over once again, but this time I made an app COMPELETY devoted to user login/logout/registration. I have finally got my login to work, but that doesn't serve me any good since I don't have any user accounts.

I'm now just asking for a ***really simple*** way for me to make a user registration page to which it allows users to make an account in order to view the homepage and be able to edit stuff on it. I have seen multiple tutorials and [documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), and really am hoping that someone can give me a reliable answer to this.

Thanks in advance.

If it helps, this is what my code looks like so far: (it's also worth mentioning that I'm using Cloud9 IDE)

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
      authenticate,
      get_user_model,
      login,
      logout,
 )
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)      
        if user is not None:
          login(request, user)
          # or any other success page
        #   return HttpResponse("Logged in")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('accounts/home')
    return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form":form, "title": title})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,

    )

User = get_user_model()

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput) 

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

    def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect Password")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active.")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

form.html (currently using this for login, open to use the same format for registration)

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block main_content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block' value='{{ title }}' />
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

(side note, I know this isn't part of what I'm primarily asking for but my login page isn't looking like the way I want it to which is like this bootstrap signin page right here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/. This is [what it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLgT.jpg)

If you can help me out with this, it would mean **the world to me**. Thank you. Also if you think it's because I didn't link to a CSS page here's what my base template looks like and my structure:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Accounts</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'accounts/signin.css' %}" />
</head>

<body>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">

            {% block main_content %} 
            {% endblock %} 
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[What My Framework Looks Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1kNv.jpg)

Sincerely appreciate whoever read this far.

Comment: @souldeux not trying to be disrespectful or anything, so take this in this politest way that you can: but what was wrong about what I said that made you want to edit and remove it?

Comment: The honest answer is that, at best, it didn't add information that would be helpful in answering your question and, at worst, it could've been read as a request to be spoon-fed (which typically elicits a negative reaction around here).

Comment: @souldeux oh, thank you. I didn't see it in that way. It wasn't what I was looking for. I was just aggravated at the fact that I'm doing this for a school project and I already had to completely start over several times because of bad tutorials that caused my apps to go completely blank and no matter what I undid, nothing would work. Anyways, I won't go on for long, but I'm still new to StackOverflow, in fact, I just made my account last week and I'm still getting used to the environment. So thanks again for the heads up!

Comment: I understand, it can take time to learn how to ask what is considered a "good" question around here. Please know that I am only trying to help. That said, to your question, is what you've posted the entirety of your views.py and forms.py files?

Comment: @souldeux thanks for understanding and the help and yes that's all I have for now. May I ask why?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you've got a view, `login_view`, that works with your form, `UserLoginForm`, to accept some POST data and try to log a user in. You can reuse a good bit of this logic to make a view that creates a user. In fact, since Django defines a `UserCreationForm` for you, you don't even have to make one yourself (assuming you're using the default auth model): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

Since this is for a school project I won't write the code for you, but think this through and you've got a good start:

1. You need a view that feeds some POST data into a form - you know how to do that.
2. Your view needs to validate that form - you know how to do that, too. Since you're using Django's built-in form you'll also have its built-in validators.
3. You'll need to save the data from that form as a new user. This part will be new. If you use the built-in `UserCreationForm`, which is a `ModelForm`, you can use `form.save()`. You should read about `ModelForms` to understand why this is the case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm On the other hand, if you decide to write your own form, then you will need to access that form data and use it to create a new user manually. You know how to access your form data - you're doing it in the login view - so all you would need to do is use that data to create a user instead of log one in. Do not use `User.objects.create` to do this - use `User.objects.create_user`. Read this to understand why: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user
4. Now you have a new user, but your view still needs to return some kind of response. What should happen next? Render a welcome page, re-direct to a new location? Up to you, but look at your login view - you already know how to both render an arbitrary template with context and how to redirect to another view. You can do anything!

I hope this serves as a jumping off point for you. Once you have read about `ModelForms`, you should have a good idea of how to implement an `edit` view like you described. Try it, then come back to SO and post specific questions with the problems you encounter along with the code you've tried. One hint, `instance` is your friend.

Lastly, your sign-in page looks funny because you're rendering the form with the plain `{{form}}` template tag. You can make it look slightly better (opinions vary) with `{{form.as_p}}` or `{{form.as_table}}`. To get it better than that, you'll either want to render each field individually (so that you can control their styling), or look into `django-crispy-forms`.